# codeigniter hook to check user is logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently trying to add to my validation hook (checking user/company is active) and I managed to get this working fine with some tinkering...

I am now trying to just do what I have been doing in each class > function (or __construct) and do a basic check for is the user is logged in using my session data 'loginuser' which is set as a Boolean...

I am trying to use this however keep getting a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. It's the same code I use in either the __construct or each public function and it works there perfect (except changed for non object)...

```
    function logged_in() {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    if(!$CI->session->userdata('loginuser')) {
        redirect('account/login');
    }
}
```

I am at a loss as to why it wont work in the hook called 'post_controller_constructor'.
I am probably overlooking something really simple but I have been going around in circles for hours and google/SO searchers are giving nothing of use. This is a really basic thing to do too...

---

ANSWER: for anyone playing at home was:

```
    function logged_in() {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    if(!$CI->session->userdata('loginuser')) {
        if (uri_string() != 'account/login' && uri_string() != 'login' && uri_string() != 'account/register'){

            $CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'Please login to continue');
            redirect('account/login');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing what you want, but there's a bit of an oversight.

You need to check if the current route is the login page before you do any kind of redirect.

I imagine that when you had the check in your controllers constructor before, you didn't put it in the account controller.

```
If (user is not logged in) {
    If (Current route is not a login page) {
        Redirect user to login page
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, being a hook it is independent of the actual controller that I am redirecting to? I am also already using the same redirect in my other code in the same controller (different function) and its working fine?

I have the following in the login controller checking if the user is logged in to prevent showing the login screen, but the variable being checked would already be unset?

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE and $this->session->userdata('loginuser') == TRUE) {
            redirect(site_url());
        }

Comment: I also have the following in routes:
$route['login'] = 'account/login';
$route['account/login'] = 'account/login';

Comment: When you put something in the post_controller_constructor hook, that code gets executed after any controller is created. That works fine when someone goes a page, they need to be logged in so it redirects them to the login page. The hook code then checks if they are logged in after the account controller is created, and redirects them to the login page. It then does the same again and again and again, hence the TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. You need to check if the current route is account/login before you redirect the user.

Comment: Ah I see, so should I be adding a check for that route in my hook, and excluding it?